# Transparent button Eclipse

Tags: android

I'm having troubles with a transparent button background. I have a 90 degree triangle with the second side transparent. The problem I'm facing is that you can activate the image button by pressing on the transparent side. is there anyway to limit it through the first side? Thanks.

[image]

ps: I'm sorry i'm new to all this.

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: I think you want to change button as transparent when pressing button otherwise with original image. Right?

Comment: `is there anyway to limit it through the first side?` **NO**. As you can see in your picture, your button is still a rectangle, even if you only see a triangle. All of its surface is sensitive to touch, even the invisible part.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by setOnTouchListener for your button (not OnClick) then you can calculate the onRawX and onRawY then compare the values if it's on your sensitive region do your work else ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but you have to do it manually. It means you should build your own View class and override `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method. and then calculate if the x and y coordinates mathces your region.